# How do I import an .inp and an IGES together into Ansys workbench?

Tags: finite-element-method, ansys, ansys-workbench, ansys-apdl

I have an `.inp` file of Ansys that is basically a mesh, that could be imported into Ansys APDL and converting to `.cdb` file.

But I also have another `.IGES` file that I should import in the same model and assemble on the first one. How do I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could import the `.inp` file containing your mesh into *Ansys Mechanical APDL*, then import your `.iges` as well (through `File/Import/IGES` or sometimes `Archive Model/Read` in `/prep7` works smoother), give your attributes to the different areas, mesh them, and export the whole model in `.cdb`.